Identify a movie that is coming. It happens in the sea
Yesterday I saw what I thought was the trailer of a movie but, instead it was a small part of the movie (one or two minutes) I got a call and could find the title of the movie. The plot is like this:

There are three people: A woman, two men and a robot. They are inside of a small ship wearing suits similar to space suits. 
They get out of the ship and they are in what looks like the middle of the sea but there are no waves. 
Two of them get off the ship looking for something on the surface while the other remains on the ship giving orders to the robot. 
Then the woman finds something valuable but gets her leg stuck under it while trying to move it. 
Things get tense because what looks like a mountain but is a huge wave is going towards them. The woman tells the other to get away and leave her behind. 
However the man in the ship commands the robot to rescue her and she gets just in time to enter the ship but the other man falls out of the ship. 
At that time the wave which could be as high as 4 Skyscrapers and the two people on the ship (man and a woman) get over the top (with many bumps around). 
I saw the trailer on my cellphone in Spain. The man who remains in the ship is a famous actor (but I can't recall his name). 
The robot has 4 articulations that can be used as legs or arms. There is an scene in which the robot is running and it looks like a ventilator. Similar to the movement of a rope when you jump the rope

That is all I know. I think it is a trailer for a coming movie. 

What country did you see the trailer in? Can you describe the people of the robot? And do you know if this is an unreleased movie?

I don't remember our policy regarding trailer ID, but this is pretty much Interstellar, and it already came out, sorry. You can still catch it on other platforms, though. ;)

Thanks that's it. I have not seen it yet

This sounds like a particular scene from the 2014 movie Interstellar.



Three astronauts, two men and one woman, along with a boxy robot, arrive on a watery planet with a mountain in the distance. They soon realize that the mountain is actually a collosal wave and try to escape. The woman gets her leg caught and the boxy robot is ordered to go save her. The woman is rescued, but one of the other astronauts doesn't make it.
